# can't run iptables-legacy using cli - centos8

Tags: centos, iptables, fedora, centos8, nftables

I have a Centos-8 machine which comes with nft-tables and with ip-tables libraries installed.

for example:
the files:
`/lib64/xtables/*`
`/lib64/libiptc.so.0.0.0`
`/lib64/libiptc.so.0`

are all exists and working, which means that I'm able to perform firewall rules which are working and affecting my machine communication.

my problem is that when I'm trying to run iptables commands from the cli and not from the library, it's not running the legacy version (it running iptables v1.8.4 (nf-tables)) which gives me the following warning:

`Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them`

and I can't find a way to run `iptables-legacy` which contains my firewall rules.

unfortunately a binary file "iptables-legacy" does not exists,
`yum` and `dnf` can't find any `iptables-legacy` package and the following rpm installation fails constantly:

https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/iptables-legacy-1.8.7-13.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html

my `/etc/alternatives` doesn't contain anything related to `iptables` and I can't find a way to access my rules from the cli.

any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. In my case the iptables-legacy was set by a Docker container and the binary file only existed when the container was running.

Did you try finding the binary via: `find / -name iptables-legacy` ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Redhat has officially stated:

> [We are not going to include iptables-legacy in RHEL8](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1873474#c4)

There is an [EPEL package for 9 though](https://rhel.pkgs.org/9/epel-x86_64/iptables-legacy-libs-1.8.7-28.el9.1.x86_64.rpm.html).  No clue why they did 9 and not 8.